# primefaces :dialog does not show 4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog, liferay-6

I have a problem with this component

when I clik on this button, nothing appears,My Problem is p:dialog is not getting displayed,Please I need your help ,

### I worked on primefaces 5.2 Liferay 6.2 , SDK 6.2 .

```
<p:commandButton id="selectButton" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View" oncomplete="introViewDialog.show()"
update=":form:displayForm" immediate="true" value="lister" >
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{introBean.selectedIntro}" value="#{intro}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

my form :

---

```
<h:form id="displayForm">
<p:dialog id="displayDialog" header="Afficher" widgetVar="introViewDialog" resizable="false" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="fold" appendToBody="true">
<h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
<h:outputText value=" id    :" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{introBean.selectedIntro.id}" />
                    <h:outputText value="titre  :" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{introBean.selectedIntro.titre}" />
                    <h:outputText value="dateDebut  :" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{introBean.selectedIntro.dateDeb}" />
                    <h:outputText value="desc   :" />
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{introBean.selectedIntro.desc}" />

                    <h:outputText value="active :"
                        rendered="#{introBean.selectedIntro.active}" />
                    <h:outputText
                        value="Elementdeclancheur"
                        rendered="#{introBean.selectedIntro.elementdeclancheur}" />

                    <h:outputText value="RTL    :"
                        rendered="#{introBean.introVO.rtl}" />



                    <h:outputText value="jsOnComplete   :" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{introBean.introVO.jsOnComplete }" />
                    <h:outputText value="themeCss   :" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{introBean.introVO.themeCss}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Take the `<h:form id="displayForm">` inside the `<p:dialog id="displayDialog">` and then change the `update` attribute associated with the command button like so, `<p:commandButton update=":displayForm:display" .../>` i.e make the `<h:panelGrid id="display" ...>` to be updated.

Comment: From your update code (`update=":form:displayForm"`), it seems that you may have nested forms, which are [not legal in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms#answer-379622). I created two forms like so, and your dialog appeared correctly:

`<h:form>
<p:commandButton id="selectButton" ... update=":displayForm" ...>
...
</p:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form id="displayForm">
<p:dialog id="displayDialog" ...>
...
</p:dialog>
</h:form>`

Comment: If the above two comments don't answer your question, please add more information such as your Primefaces version, Liferay version, and an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: thank you for your reply, I worked on primefaces 5.2 Liferay 6.2 .

Comment: I tried to follow your proposal but I have an exeption: Can not find component for phrase "DisplayForm" referenced from "_1_WAR_introportlet_: form: introTabl .

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the widgetVar via following code `oncomplete="introViewDialog.show()"`. This won't work on PF5.2, since it is deprecated in PF4 and removed in PF5. There should be an error in your browser console.

Quote from http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3184:

> In 4.0, widgetVar.method() usage to access the client side api of a component has been deprecated in favor of PF(‘widgetVar’).show() to keep the window scope clean.

Please use following syntax: `oncomplete="PF('introViewDialog').show()";`

Comment: If the OP runs 'backwardscompatibility mode' it still works, even with 6.0.x and 6.1-SNAPSHOT