# primefaces dialog does not show up on button click

Tags: primefaces

I have primefaces version `6.0` and i'm experiencing this issue of a dialog not showing up.

This is the button.

```
<p:commandButton id="newRequestButton"
                 class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
                 value="New Request"
                 update=":newRequestForm:newRequestDialog" 
                 oncomplete="PF('newRequest').show()" />
```

And this is the dialog

```
<p:dialog header="Request Definitions" widgetVar="newRequest"
                  resizable="true" width="600" showEffect="explode"
                  hideEffect="explode" modal="true" height="300" 
                  class="modal-dialog">
    <h:form id='newRequestForm'>
        <h:panelGrid id="newRequestDialog" columns="1" cellpadding="4"        
                     class="modal-content">

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Whatcould be the problem. I have followed several answers such as this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239514/primefaces-dialog-does-not-show-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381602/primefaces-dialog-commandbutton) to no avail.

EDIT:
Where exactly are `dialogs` supposed to be placed in respect to `forms` and the `commandButtons` activating them?

Comment: What did you investigate in logging? Browser console? Did you try updating dialog content and then showing it instead of updating the dialog?

Comment: @Kukeltje as you can see i'm updating the `h:panelGrid` which has the content of the dialog

Comment: Sorry, misread that... :-( Form should be in a dialog when it is modal and has a 'appendTo' of body (see the PF docs. The position in relation to the commandButton is not really relevant. There is not reason this should not work, unless the call to the server is not made due to the commandButton not working at all, which can be tested by replacing the 'show' with a plain javascript alert.

Comment: @Kukeltje even with `appendTo` nothing happens, why would the `commandButtons' not work?

Comment: I did not say you should use appendTo, I stated that when it is used, you need the form to be inside the dialog. Why would commandButtons not work, well.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandlink-commandbutton-ajax-backing-bean-action-listener-method-not-invoked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that I had included both bootstrap jquery and the jquery bundled by primefaces. Disabling the bootstrap jquery worked.

Comment: Then you most likely had errors in the JS console... Next time please create a [mcve]... Now nothing that cause your problem was visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put commandButton and dialog in h:form tag with a id attribute like "form" and then in update attribute of commandButton, first write "form"(value of id attribute of h:form which contains button and dialog). try the below code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    <h:head>
   </h:head>
    <h:body>
    <h:form id="form">

         <p:commandButton id="newRequestButton"
                 class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" 
                 value="New Request"
                 update=":form:newRequestDialog" 
                 oncomplete="PF('newRequest').show()" />

         <p:dialog header="Request Definitions" widgetVar="newRequest"
                  resizable="true" width="600" showEffect="explode"
                  hideEffect="explode" modal="true" height="300" 
                  class="modal-dialog">

       <p:outputPanel id="newRequestDialog" style="text-align:center;"> 

        <p:panelGrid  columns="1" class="modal-content">

        </p:panelGrid>

       </p:outputPanel>

         </p:dialog> 

        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: My code is actually similar but the forms are not nested. But this still does not work. Im using chrome. Turned on developer options and on the console I receive no error messages or any messages at all on clicking.

Comment: well the above code is working fine in primefaces 5.0

Comment: now try the above edited code, it's not containing nested form and and dialog is also opening on  clicking commandButton

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: What is the issue?  Is dialog is not opening ? or The panelGrid is not getting updated??

Comment: The dialog is not opening

Comment: @Obby did you put your p:commandButton tag and p:dialog  tag in h:form tag as stated above??? And Did you write this ""update=":form:newRequestDialog" ""  in p:commandButton??? ""newRequestDialog is the id of p:outputpanel and it is not an id of p:panelgrid.""

Comment: I actually copied the same exact dialog above and replaced it where my own was

Comment: @Obby good to hear that. if you did also update p:commandButton update attribute and have p:commandButton and p:dialog in h:form with id="form" then your code should have been working.

Comment: @Obby try the above answer(code) in a separate .xhtml file , that will surely work and may be you will get something helpful for future.